# При создании динамического блока не работает mask'a для ввода

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

С помощью JS создается динамический блок, часть кода:

```js
divtest.innerHTML = 
    '<div class="blockname">'+
        '<form action="" method="post">'+
            'Дата рождения'+
            '<input type="text" name="birthday[]" id="birthday" class="form-control" data-mask="00/00/0000" placeholder="__/__/____">'+
         '</form>'+
    '</div>';
```

Блоки создаются, но в них не работает маска, если на странице отдельно взять этот код (не динамически), то в нем уже все работает. Что может быть не так?
[image: Скриншот работы одного и того же кода при обычном встраивании и при добавлении динамиечски через кнопку]

Comment: Попробуйте по id обращаться.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#test').append('<div class="blockname">'+
        '<form action="" method="post">'+
            'Дата рождения'+
            '<input type="text" name="birthday[]" id="birthday" class="form-control" data-mask="00/00/0000" placeholder="__/__/____">'+
         '</form>'+'</div>'
)
```

Comment: Не работает, проблема видимо в чем-то другом, добавил фото, чтоб было понятнее

Comment: тебе надо чтобы при вводе были слешы?

Comment: Да, на фото самый первый пример, то как должно быть

Comment: это дело не в placeholder, а тебе надо обрабатывать событие onchange инпута и формотировать

Comment: точнее onkeypress

Comment: $('#test').append('<div class="blockname">'+
        '<form action="" method="post">'+
            'Дата рождения'+
            '<input type="text" name="birthday[]" id="birthday" class="form-control" data-mask="00/00/0000"  placeholder="__/__/____">'+
         '</form>'+'</div>'
);


$('#birthday').on('keyup', function(event){
  let value = $(this).val();
  if(value.length == 2)
     $(this).val( $(this).val()+'/')
    if(value.length == 5)
     $(this).val( $(this).val()+'/')
})

Comment: я грубо ошибся и перепутал, писал про placeholder, но на самом деле не работает mask